# How to use operator and && for show "something"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, taxonomy

I have code to display "Hello World" based on size attributes.

The code is :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','show_something', 5 );
function show_something() {
  if (is_tax('pa_size')) {
    echo "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
    }
}
```

The code above it's worked.

But what i want actually is add an additional one condition that is a color attribute that has a red value/term in addition to size attributes for displaying "Hello World"

What I have tried is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','show_something', 5 );
function show_something() {
  if (is_tax('pa_size') && is_tax(array('pa_color','red'))) {
    echo "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
    }
}
```

But it didn't work.

Can anyone take a minute to help me fix this code please?

Any help is greatly appreciated,
thank you

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/ has explanation & examples

Comment: Hi @7uc1f3r thanks for the prompt reply.

I'm just learning about wordpress.
So I don't really understand.
But I tried to read the reference you gave and the closest is this code (To check for more than one taxonomy, you can use an array. That’s useful when you want to display some code only on those taxonomy pages.
`if ( is_tax( array('channel', 'broadcaster') ) ) {
// your code
}`. So I tried by changing `if (is_tax('pa_size') && is_tax(array('pa_color','red')))`  to if `(is_tax(array('pa_size','pa_color','red')))` but it didn't work. Can you give an example by editing the code above?

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content','show_something', 5 );
function show_something() {
  if (is_tax('pa_size') && is_tax('pa_color','red')) {
    echo "<h2>Hello World</h2>";
    }
}
```

The first argument of [is_tax](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tax/) is the taxonomy (`pa_color`), the second is the term (`red`). By providing an array, you're telling WordPress to check in taxonomies `pa_color` and `red`.